# Builtin\Administrators doesn't permit access

Tags: security, sql-server-2016, connectivity

I have created a SQL 2016 (Developer) instance on a new build machine. For ease of use, when we do this, we grant `Builtin\Administrators` sysadmin rights on the instance. This allows all developers on the machine to be able to have full control over their local instance.

In previous versions of SQL (e.g. 2014). This works fine. However, when I try it on SQL 2016, this does not appear to work.

Whenever I attempt to log into the machine with Windows Authentication, I receive the following error:

> Login failed for user 'xxxx'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> ---
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456&LinkId=20476
>
> ---
>
> Server Name: xxxx
>
> Error Number: 18456
>
> Severity: 14
>
> State: 1
>
> Line Number: 65536

Below are shots of the `Builtin\Administrators` group within SQL:

[image: General Tab]

[image: Status Tab]

As you can see, it's set up and enabled.

The server *is* configured for Mixed Mode authentication. If I add a Login for the user directly, Windows Authentication will work successfully.

Below is the error log from SQL, which includes a bit more information:

[image]

For clarity, the user is in a group which is a member of the Administrators group on the machine. Running `whoami /groups` on the commandline confirms that the local Administrators group *is* listed.

What do I need to do to get `Builtin\Administrators` to allow successful logins?

Comment: Did you add a group into Builtin\administrators, or all accounts individually?

Comment: @StijnWynants It's an AD group thats in the Administrators group on the computer. This has worked on other machines fine. Although I did attempt to add the user manually, and it didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: What does your error log on SQL Server say?

Comment: Ah. Missed those logs. Apparently "login lacks connect sql permission" - but the group does appear to have it in the screenshot above

Comment: can you add a screen of the errorlog message?

Comment: @StijnWynants Done.

Comment: check out https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2016/07/09/why-do-i-get-the-infrastructure-error-for-login-failures/

Comment: @StijnWynants Damn. I think thats exactly it. I'm not running SSMS as admin. And checking the other user machines, they all appear to have themselves actually in as users explicitly. If you want to create an answer around that, I will accept it once I confirm 100% on the machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented, UAC is blocking your connection to SQL Server. Run it as administrator and it should be fine.